# Calling async WCF without service reference using ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I'm using **.NET 3.5** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263655/wcf-channelfactory-asynchronous-call) is a related question but using TPL Async Library, since I'm in 3.5 I need another approach.

I used to call a WCF asynchronously by adding a service reference and creating its async operations using Visual Studio 2010.

Now I've created a dynamic proxy using the `CreateChannel<T>` of the `ChannelFactory` class and I need to call a method in async way. This is how I create the WCF proxy:

```
    public MyInterface Proxy { get; set; }

    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/myEndpoint");
    Proxy = ChannelFactory<MyInterface>.CreateChannel(binding, ep); 

    // I call my method
    Proxy.MyMethod();

    [ServiceContract]
    public Interface MyInterface
    {
      [OperationContract]
      void MyMethod();
    }
```

I don't need the service response.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400798/how-to-make-a-call-to-my-wcf-service-asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want to make your Proxy.MyMethod to run async by means of .NET 3.5, you can use standart BeginInvoke of the Delegate class, like this:

```
 //Make a delegate for your Proxy.MyMethod
 private delegate void MyDelegate();
```

Then in code, you just call your method async:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/myEndpoint");
Proxy = ChannelFactory<MyInterface>.CreateChannel(binding, ep); 
var delInstance = new MyDelegate(Proxy.MyMethod);
var result = delInstance.BeginInvoke();
```

If you need to check something about results, use result variable for this

Comment: Thank you. Since is not the solution I was looking for it seems to works as async manner. However I edit your answer because the way you declared the delegate didn't allowed me to run in async way.

Comment: @senyorToni You are welcome. Also if it is suiable for you to use proxi instead of ChannelFactory, you can create proxi class for your client using svcutil with /async directive. This will automaticly generate you BeginMyMethod method, which would start async. Without results tour call would be a single  line of code: new YourProxiClient().BeginMyMethod();