# How to do fire and forget WCF API from console app?

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application, fire-and-forget

I have a C# console application that needs to call a WCF API for updating DB. Since the console application doesn't need to wait on the result of the WCF API, I would like to launch it asynchronously. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously consume synchronous WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638828/asynchronously-consume-synchronous-wcf-service)

Comment: You can place your call into a different thread. in that case if main thread dies than your thread will continue work until it is finished.