# Custom WCF channel throws NullReferenceException on ChannelBase.EndInvoke

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a very simple WCF service that I need to write a custom client for, that has to override `CreateChannel`, but when I call `EndInvoke` inside my `ChannelBase` implementation I get

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.ServiceModel
  StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.MapAsyncEndInputs(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, IAsyncResult& result, Object[]& outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at Client.TestServiceClient.TestServiceChannel.<SayHello>b__1_0(IAsyncResult result) 
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong and the StackTrace isn't helping me either, google didn't turn up anything useful. My solution is using `.net 4.6.2` and the call to the service succeeds (it prints to console), but `EndInvoke` throws from within framework code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Minimal repro:

```
namespace Service {
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService {
        [OperationContract]
        void SayHello();
    }

    public class TestService : ITestService {
        public void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}


namespace Host {
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using Service;

    internal static class Program {
        private static void Main() {
            var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None), "http://localhost:13377/");
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace Client {
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
    using Service;

    public class TestServiceClient : ClientBase<ITestService>, ITestService {
        public TestServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : base(binding, remoteAddress) {}

        public void SayHello() => Channel.SayHello();

        protected override ITestService CreateChannel() => new TestServiceChannel(this);

        private class TestServiceChannel: ChannelBase<ITestService>, ITestService {
            public TestServiceChannel(ClientBase<ITestService> client) : base(client) {}

            public void SayHello() => base.BeginInvoke("SayHello", new object[0], result => base.EndInvoke("SayHello", new object[0], result), null);
        }
    }

    internal static class Program {
        private static void Main() {
            var client = new TestServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:13377/"));
            client.SayHello();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that calling `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` pair is only allowed if the service contract has `Begin...`/`End...` pair of methods. WCF internally analyses contract interface and if it sees the method which looks like async one (starts from "Begin", has 3 or more parameters, etc), then it initializes some internal structures which are later used by `EndInvoke` (in the `MapAsyncEndInputs`).

If you want to use WCF infrastructure for async calls, then client-side service contract interface should be async-style. Alternatively, you need to wrap the whole channel object to provide async operations on top.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263655/wcf-channelfactory-asynchronous-call) (option #3) to see how it was done for Task-based async pattern.

Comment: Do you mean that the service must implement the Begin/End pair, or just that the client's version of the service contract must implement them?

Comment: WCF has the benefit of having independent async implementation of client and/or server. Therefore if you need async behavior on the client side, then you can implement async WCF client and keep service synchronous.